# Try to run a nodejs command line but got unexpected error

Tags: node.js

I try to run a command in nodejs:
`$ sed -nr 's#^0 (.*)#training/\1#p' CSDMC2010_SPAM/CSDMC2010_SPAM/SPAMTrain.label | xargs node spamfilter.js -s`

But got an error:
`The term 'sed' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and

try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ sed -nr 's#^0 (.*)#training/\1#p' CSDMC2010_SPAM/CSDMC2010_SPAM/SPAMT ...
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sed:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

Try many ways to fix but it's useless, anyone who can help ? Very appreciate

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with Node.js.  You're trying to run `sed` (something found on Linux and what not) within PowerShell.

Comment: from what I can see, this is not an issue with node & an issue with this `sed` utility you are using.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce a simple spam filter with node.js and encounter this problem, anyway to run this command on powershell of windows ?